# Which version of Axon framework is compatible with Spring Boot 3.2.1?

Tags: spring, axon-framework

I have problem with axon framework, please help me. Command statement not found when i working with springboot

I tried many version axon framework config with maven but not work

I used Command Statement to config event and use autowird but spring not found

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.